# Equating two different sample sizes

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, test-equating

I have two scores, Score 1 and score 2. Score 1 has 150 samples and Score 2 has 85 samples. Is it possible to equate scores, especially using R packages?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "equate scores?"  What is it that you are wanting to do in plain English?